# Revit file not supported (while working in A360 viewer) but IFC is working

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-model-derivative

For a proof of concept I'm playing around in Postman with the Autodesk Forge API's and I'm doign the following.

- authenticate
- create & get bucket
- upload model (in IFC and Revit) in bucket
- translate it
- extract meta-data.

With IFC files everything is working like a charm but it's not working with Revit files no matter what I do or which Revit file I try. 
I tried 3 of my own Revit files (that do work in Autodesk 360 viewer based on Forge) and Autodesk's sample Revit file Basic Sample Project 2016

I'm wondering if it could be something specific in my API calls that I'm missing.

Below are two screenshots of two calls that I'm doing;

- [put model in bucket](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1dVJT.png)
- [validate translation giving error with Revit but working with IFC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vHoad.png)

Hope you can help, because I'm very stuck.

Comment: can you also describe your `POST job` call? it seems the file was not uploaded properly...

Comment: Sure... ![image of post call](http://imgur.com/hTJUHxX) but this POST call initiates the translation. The put I posted before actually uploads the file.

Comment: can you check the SHA1 with your original file, something like http://onlinemd5.com (which may indicate a problem during upload)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion; The SHA1 is indeed different. 6D0DEFE9C4F8E36C7786254A3D07F9991DBF8D91 for the original and the uploaded one is in the screenshot. 

What could be the cause of this? Tried uploading multiple times; no Revit file works, IFC however has no problem.

Could it be how I construct the call? In postman in the body I put the file as form-data under the key file. Tried binary payload first but then postman crashes. And again this construction has worked with IFC files.

Comment: Bart, sorry this delay, the call should be the same, but you may have problems, for instance, with big files, where a resumable upload can help. Other than that, would suggest one of our samples, like modelderivative.apphb.com